# Safari web inspector does not display app elements

Tags: ios, xcode, ionic-framework, safari

I was able to build from Xcode and display my application on my phone, and when opening safari web inspector I can select the app, however, when the inspector opens ***sometimes*** none of the DOM elements are displaying (nothing of the app is actually showing in the inspector).

Has anyone come across this and know why it's happening and what the solution is?

Safari web inspector elements only show the following:

[image: DOM Elements not loading the application elements]

[image: App does not load in the inspector]

Cordova CLI: 6.5.0
Ionic Framework Version: 2.0.0-rc.4
Ionic CLI Version: 2.2.1
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.2.0
Ionic App Scripts Version: 1.2.0
ios-deploy version: 1.9.1
ios-sim version: 5.0.13
 
OS: OS X El Capitan 10.11.6
Node Version: v7.4.0
Xcode version: Xcode 8.2.1 Build version 8C1002
Safari: 10.0.3
iPhone 5: iOS 10.2.1